# Android HTML 5 video in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Is there any way to have android 2.x and 4.x devices play HTML 5 video using the video tag in my phonegap app? I am using the following format:

```
<video id="homevideo" width="100%" autobuffer controls>
   <source src="http://myurl.com/myfile.mp4" />
</video>
```

My app is in orientation portrait only. In my app when I play a video on the iPhone my video pops into it's own little video player that is defaulted to full screen and allows me to rotate it to landscape. Is there any way to get this functionality on android using phonegap build? Or is the https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer plugin still the recommended way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to have android 2.x and 4.x devices play HTML 5 video
>   using the video tag in my phonegap app?

The `<video></video>` tag is fully supported in Android back to v2.3 and partially supported in v2.1/2.2. See [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=video).

> My app is in orientation portrait only. In my app when I play a video
>   on the iPhone my video pops into it's own little video player that is
>   defaulted to full screen and allows me to rotate it to landscape. Is
>   there any way to get this functionality on android using phonegap
>   build? Or is the https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer plugin still
>   the recommended way to go?

Plug-in's generally provide the best cross-device support and standardization but I would test with out and test with and see what functionality you like the best.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dom, I've tried it with video tag in 2.x and 4.x and while it works it doesn't work well (can't switch to landscape mode and seems kind of buggy with the start/pause actions). I may have to give up "PhoneGap Build" so that I can use plugins.

Comment: I ended up dropping in [videojs](http://www.videojs.com/) as my video player so I wouldn't need a plugin and worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

@Chirs: I suggest you to use the following plug-in:
http://cordova.apache.org/news/2013/10/21/cordova-registry.html
is Tested on Android API 15 - 17 and works very well for me, I hope it can help you

Comment: The URL you give is not found

Comment: yes that link is over, they have moved everything to http://cordova.apache.org/news/2013/10/21/cordova-registry.html